# Very long ubuntu startup time

Tags: startup, dmesg

I've just installed Ubuntu (on an SSD) and startup takes over two minutes. I've checked "dmesg" and found a clear 90 seconds process that probably shouldn't be there.

```
[   13.831788] audit: type=1400 audit(1514109052.015:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app//oxide_helper" pid=917 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.832582] audit: type=1400 audit(1514109052.015:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=919 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  102.796317] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
[  102.841385] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down
[  102.841430] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
[  103.045127] amdgpu 0000:09:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[  103.045128] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[  103.244799] kauditd_printk_skb: 18 callbacks suppressed
```

I'm just not sure how to interpret this. Is it because of the ADDRCONF or because of the process before? I've tried to startup with the ethernet cable removed, but it didn't help. Any advice?

Comment: Run the command `systemd-analyze blame` and include the output in your question please.